# Determining the values of the unknown variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

### Assume X and Y are random variables with the following joint distribution

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
X/Y &  0  & 1 & 2\\ \hline
 1& 0,2& \alpha  &\beta\\ \hline
 2& \gamma &0,1 &\delta\\ \hline
 3&  \mu&\kappa &0,3\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Find the values of $\alpha, \beta\, \gamma, \delta,$ $\kappa, \mu$so that the conditions below will hold.

$P(X=1)= 0,4 $ ; $ P(X=2)= 0,3$ ; $P(Y=0)= 0,2$ ; $P(Y=2)= 0,6$

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your post to include your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$P(X=3)= 1-P(X=1)-P(X=2)=0.3$, hence

$$P(X=3)=\mu+ \kappa+0.3=0.3$$

Since $\mu, \kappa \geq 0$, $$\mu=0, \kappa = 0$$

Knowing $\mu$, and the value of $P(Y=0)$, you should be able to compute $\gamma$.

Knowing $\kappa=0$ and $P(Y=1)=1-0.2-0.6=0.2$, you should be able to compute $\alpha$.